# How to create form for each item of the data object in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4, silvershop

Using the package `"silvershop/core": "^3@dev"`, I'm extending class `SilverShop\Page\AccountPageController` named `AccountPageControllerExtension`

Scenario: An authenticated user can store the current order as a `Quote` and then edit the quantities of the items in the account page.

On saving the order as a quote, it's changing the status of the order from `Cart` to `Quote`

Now, to edit the items, I've got a `QuoteForm` extending `Form` which is inspired by `SilverShop\Forms\CartForm` which is displaying the items fine.

The problem lies on form submission. Since this `QuoteForm` is individual for each `Order`, I'm not able to figure out how to submit the form.

Class `QuoteForm`

```
class QuoteForm extends Form {

    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $quote;

    public function __construct( $controller, $quoteID = null, $name = 'QuoteForm') {

        if( empty($quoteID) ){
            return false;
        }

        $this->quote = Order::get_by_id($quoteID);
        $items = $this->quote->Items();

        $fields = FieldList::create(
        QuoteEditField::create( $items, 'Items')
            ->setTemplate('Shop\FormField\QuoteEditField')
            ->setTitle('')
        );

        $fields->add(HiddenField::create('QuoteID', 'QuoteID', $quoteID));

        $actions = FieldList::create(
            $update_action = FormAction::create('updateQuote', 'Update')
        );

        parent::__construct( $controller, $name, $fields, $actions );
    }

    public function updateQuote($data, $form){
        Debug::dump($data);

        return Controller::curr()->redirectBack();
    }

}
```

Function `QuoteForm` present in the `AccountPageControllerExtension` class

```
public function QuoteForm($order_id){
    $form = QuoteForm::create($this->owner, $order_id);
    return $form;
}
```

which is the called on the template as

```
<% loop $Quotes %>

    ... title, order date, etc..

    $Up.QuoteForm($ID)
<% end_loop %>
```

Once the form is submitted this is the error received

```
[Emergency] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest is not a subclass of DataObject
POST /account/QuoteForm/
Line 155 in /var/www/app/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/ORM/DataObjectSchema.php
```

Which I'm guessing is coming because function `QuoteForm` accepts an argument `$order_id` but on submission it's setting the `$order_id` as an instance of `HTTPRequest` because I see this line in the trace 
`{Redacted}\QuoteForm->__construct(SilverShop\Page\AccountPageController, SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest)`

How to submit the form for each quote individually?